# Stored procedure to extract NOT NULL values from a table based on (User Input)

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, tbl1 is where I have stored a business rule that would contain queries to extract NOT NULL values from tbl2.

I have used a left Join and that is working:
query below:

```
SELECT Data.SSO, Data.Amount FROM Data
LEFT JOIN Configuration ON
Data.SSO_Id = Configuration.ID_Field
WHERE
Data.SSO IS NOT NULL
```

I have built a Stored procedure that should take an input from user, example 'SSO' and retrieve NOT NULL values for this input from other table:

Code Below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spGetNotNullVal
@User_Input nvarchar(max),
@Result_Not_Null nvarchar(max) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Result_Not_Null =  Configuration.Business_Rule FROM Configuration 
        WHERE Configuration.Field_Name = @User_Input
END

--Executing the stored procedure/Will sore @Result_Not_Null Value into @Final_Result and print it.

DECLARE @Final_Result nvarchar(max)
EXECUTE spGetNotNullVal 'Legal Entity', @Final_Result Output
PRINT @Final_Result
```

The problem is, that when I execute the @Final_Result it spits back the same Left Join query rather than executing it and giving the table:

```
SELECT Data.SSO, Data.Amount FROM Data
LEFT JOIN Configuration ON
Data.SSO_Id = Configuration.ID_Field
WHERE
Data.SSO IS NOT NULL
```

Where am I going wrong? Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This TSQL just gets the business rule from the Configuration table

`EXECUTE spGetNotNullVal 'Legal Entity', @Final_Result Output`

but doesn't actually execute the contents.

For that you need to try something like this

`EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Final_Result`

Comment: He is executing it in right way: `EXECUTE spGetNotNullVal 'Legal Entity', @Final_Result Output`

Comment: @B3S OP was getting the business rule with the procedure fine but wasn't executing the business rule it self.

Comment: so i completely missed what he was looking for. My mistake in this case :) please consider editing your answer so i can remove my downvote.